# LINQ dynamic query

Tags: linq, dynamic

How to dynamically generate LINQ query:

```
int[] IDArray = {55, 36};

public IQueryable<ContactListView> FindAllContacts(int loggedUserID, int[] IDArray)
{
    var result = (
                 from contact in db.Contacts

                 //Start of dynamic part...
                 where 
                 contact.UserID == loggedUserID
                 foreach (var id in IDArray)
                 {
                     where contact.UserID == id 
                 }
                 // End of dynamic part

                 orderby contact.ContactID descending                         
                 select new ContactListView
                 {
                     ContactID = contact.ContactID,
                     FirstName = contact.FirstName,
                     LastName = contact.LastName                            
                 });

    return result;
}
```

Thanks,
Ile

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can't you just use `Contains`?  I assume you want to generate a query that has an `IN` clause.  There's an example of that here: [Creating in queries with linq to sql](http://blog.wekeroad.com/2008/02/27/creating-in-queries-with-linq-to-sql/).

```
int[] IDArray = {55, 36};

public IQueryable<ContactListView> FindAllContacts(int loggedUserID, int[] IDArray)
{
    var result = (
                 from contact in db.Contacts
                 where contact.UserID == loggedUserID
                     && IDArray.Contains( contact.UserID )
                 orderby contact.ContactID descending                         
                 select new ContactListView
                 {
                     ContactID = contact.ContactID,
                     FirstName = contact.FirstName,
                     LastName = contact.LastName                            
                 });

    return result;
}
```

Comment: `&& IDArray.Contains( id )` - the `id` doesn't exist in this scope? Could you please be more precise? Thanks

Comment: `IDArray.Contains( id )`

should be

    `IDArray.Contains( contact.UserID )`

Answer (score 2):

You probably want `where IDArray.Contains(contact.UserID)`