# Dynamic Linq Query Help?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

How do you write a dynamic Linq query for the following simple search criteria?
1) StudentNumber
2) LastName
3) LastName and FirstName

```
//if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(StudentNumber))
var results  = (from s in Students              
                where s.StudentNumber == 1001
                select s
               );

//else if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(LastName) & (String.IsNullOrEmpty(FirstName))

var results  = (from s in Students              
                where s.LastName == "Tucker"
                select s
               );

//else if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(LastName) & (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(FirstName))            
var results  = (from s in Students              
                where s.LastName == "Tucker" && s.FirstName == "Ron"
                select s
               );
```

Comment: try to follow this thread.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2827446/linq-dynamic-query

Regards.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to declare your `results` variable outside of any individual query. This will allow you append different filters based upon your varying criteria, and append as many filters as you need. An example:

```
var results = Students.AsEnumerable(); // use .AsQueryable() for EF or Linq-to-SQL

if (!string.IsNullorEmpty(StudentNumber)) 
{
    results = results.Where(s => s.StudentNumber.Equals(StudentNumber));
}
else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(LastName))
{
    results = results.Where(s => s.LastName.Equals(LastName));

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(FirstName))
    {
         results = results.Where(s => s.FirstName.Equals(FirstName));
         // filter is in addition to predicate against LastName
    }
}

// results can be used here
```

If dealing with Linq-to-Entities or -Sql, type the initial query with `Students.AsQueryable();` so that the filtering happens at the database rather than inside the application.

---

> Is there a way I can construct the WHERE clause first and use it in a
>   Linq query without if...else

If you want to build the entire `where` before the first step of the query, it's the same logic. You are conditionally building the predicate, so you will have some sort of if/else involved. However, to build the entire predicate first, you could build against a `Func<Student, bool>` for Linq to Objects.

```
Func<Student, bool> predicate;
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(StudentNumber))
{
    predicate = s => s.StudentNumber.Equals(StudentNumber);
}
else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(LastName))
{
    predicate = s => s.LastName.Equals(LastName);

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(FirstName))
    {
        Func<Student, bool> p = predicate;
        predicate = s => p(s) && s.FirstName.Equals(FirstName);
    }
}
else
{
    predicate = s => true;
}

var query = Students.Where(predicate);
```

You'll notice it's the exact same if/else structure. You could collapse that down into a complicated conditional expression

```
Func<Student, bool> predicate;
predicate = s =>
    !string.IsNullOrEmpty(StudentNumber)
    ? s.StudentNumber.Equals(StudentNumber)
    : !string.IsNullOrEmpty(LastName)
        ? !string.IsNullOrEmpty(FirstName)
            ? s.LastName.Equals(LastName) && s.FirstName.Equals(FirstName)
            : s.LastName.Equals(LastName)
        : true;

var query = Students.Where(predicate);
```

But I find that pretty well difficult to follow, certainly as compared to the longer if/else. This predicate is also bigger than the one we build via the if/else, because this one contains *all* the logic, it's not just the logic we conditionally added.

Comment: Is there a way I can construct the WHERE clause first and use it in a Linq query without if...else?

Comment: @rk1962, how do you think you'd go about building the `where` conditionally without using some sort of if/else construct (including the conditional statement)? You could build an `Func<Student, bool>` (or `Expression<Func<Student, Bool>>` in the case of EF/SQL) and pass that into your query, but the idea would be the same, it's just a matter of *when* you expressed it, not so much as *if*.

Comment: I did some research and found a similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/798553/user-defined-filter-for-linq.  I will read Dynamic Linq Query Library article http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx to see if it helps.  Thank you!

Comment: @AnthonyPegram In your first example, if you specify the type of results as IQueryable<Student> (or IEnumerable), you wouldn't need the .AsQueryable (or AsEnumerable) extension method. This is a case where being explicit in the typing is better than using type inference (var). Either works, however it is worth repeating that if you use AsEnumerable, any subsequent filtering will be done in the client (LINQ to Objects) rather than on the server.

Comment: @JimWooley, actually, the earliest version of my answer (as I was typing it, not in the revision history) used the explicit typing as you describe. Then I thought to myself that "nobody ever uses it, might as well make my answer conform." If you want to explicitly type it, by all means! However, most folks around here do not want to type `IQueryable<Student>`. (Many even consider it *noise,* even if we all agree that is certainly the type we want.)

Comment: It is noise if the compiler infers the type correctly, but in cases where you want a base type, explicitly typing is often the best option.

Comment: Thank you Anthony and Jim!  I used your first solution and it worked fine.